# pfsense Server Load-balancing on LAN Interface

Tags: nat, pfsense, load-balancing

I am trying to load balance a couple of web servers from the LAN side as I don't need access from the WAN so that clients on the LAN can access these web servers:
LAN IP is 192.168.10.1

1. I created a virtual IP VIP: 192.168.10.10
2. Created a pool "POOL01" that contains two web servers with IPs 192.168.20.1 and 192.168.20.2 on port 8080
3. Created a virtual server using the VIP created earlier 192.168.10.10:8090 that points to "POOL01"
4. I created a rule on FW to allow all traffic to VIP 192.168.10.10 to any service from any source
5. WebGUI redirect is Disabled
6. Monitor is ICMP

I can ping VIP 192.168.10.10, but telnet to port 8090 is not open and I don't understand why, also when I look at the status, it shows that virtual server is down. LAN interface itself can reach these servers as well.

Any clues on this issue.

pfsense version: 2.4.3-RELEASE-p1

Thanks

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the full device configuration. We cannot guess what is wrong. Spculation and guessing are off-topic here.